# when i try to login first time using Fb login i get error and 2 second time when i try to login i loggedin succesfully

Tags: facebook, cakephp, facebook-login

when first time i try to login I get error message in exception:\

> [message] => An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

The following is my code:

```
Configure::load('facebook');
$appId      = Configure::read('Facebook.appId');
$app_secret = Configure::read('Facebook.secret');
$facebook   = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $appId, // fb app id (mentioned in facebook.php)
    'secret' => $app_secret, // fb secret key
    'cookie' => true,
    'oauth ' => true
));

//======================================
// to get loggedin user details
//======================================

$user = $facebook->getUser();

//$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
if (!empty($user)) {
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        pr($e);
    }
}
```

//===========================
// view

```
function facebookLogin(detectedTimeZone){

    window.open('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<?php echo $appId; ?>&display=popup&redirect_uri='+base_url+'/users/facebook_login/scope=email','','width=600, height=400');
       }

       <div style="float:left;"><a onclick="facebookLogin(detectedTimeZone);" href="javascript: void(0);" id="fb-auth"><img src="/images/fblogin.png"></a>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Where are you putting all this code?

Comment: This behavior point to a cookie issue. Are you refreshing the page / redirecting after the login or are you using Ajax? In either case, the Facebook cookie from their js sdk must be set for `getUser()` to find the user.

Comment: andre i have written above code in controller
@costa i am refreshing the page

Comment: Do you want to use the JS SDK to provide a login button, or do the login redirect via php?

Comment: I have updated  my code... please review